# Time tracking software with image links

Tags: project-management, calendar, time-management

I'm looking for a time management/calendar software (can be a desktop application for Windows, or a web app) mainly for projects that has the following features.

1) Each project has its own column on the timeline:

|  []
|     []
|        []

The above shows the timeline for a day, with time spent on three projects consecutively (where each project has its own column).

2) Has a day view that is continuous - where I can scroll downwards through the hours of days continually.

3) Enables linking of each chunk of time spent for a project to an image (e.g. via desktop location or URL), and I can hover over or click on the chunk to have the image appear.

|  []
|     []
|        []

For example, I can hover over or click on a chunk above, which will have a linked image appear.

Answer (score 1):

ManicTime Tracker has a lot of functions, he can't link images to a project though

but he offers a lot of filtering and tagging mechanics,

it shows which programm was in focus what amount of time and which document was open in it

it's not a web-app, and I haven't used it for tracking a team yet, so no experience on how good that works